# jQuery Validation of six input fields as a group

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to implement 6 form fields which allows users to key in a 6 digit code that is sent to their email. [image]

All these 6 fields are required and the error message will appear on the right hand side if any one of them is not filled.

In my code, I am having the following issues

1) When they are ALL NOT filled, the error message appears. This is correct.

2) As long as one of them is filled, the error message disappears.

2a) Only when I am clicking on the "Submit" button then the error message briefly appears. Once I release the click, the error message is gone. I am not sure if it's because the error messages are overridden.

Can a method be written to check that as long as one of the fields is not filled, then the error message to be displayed?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#verification_form").validate({
        groups: {
            inputGroup: "num1 num2 num3 num4 num5 num6"        
        },                  
        rules: {
            Name: {
                required: true,
                maxlength:50
            },
            Email: {
                required: true,
                email:true,
                maxlength:50
            },
            num1: {
                required:true
            },
            num2: {
                required:true                                           
            },
            num3: {
                required:true
            },
            num4: {
                //required: "#divVerifyEmail:visible",
                required:true                                           
            },
            num5: {
                required:true
            },
            num6: {
                required:true                                           
            }                                                                                                       
        },


        highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
             $(element).closest('.form-group').find('.error-msg').text(error.text());
        },
        unhighlight: function(element) {
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success')
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
            return false; // for demo
        }   
})
```

Comment: I am not sure exactly what is the problem, can you create a fiddle?

Comment: It might be a good idea to also show us the relevant HTML markup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `groups` option merely lumps all messages together into one.  If all six fields have their own `required` rule, then when one field is satisfied the message will clear, then when another field is not satisfied the message will come back, and so forth, toggling on/off/etc as you move around the fields.

This option was not intended for multiple fields with different messages.  It was intended for use with complex rules like `require_from_group` that would always put the same message on several fields at the same time.  The `groups` option is working the way it's supposed to work, but it's not what you want.

You may want to try the `require_from_group` rule instead.

```
$("#verification_form").validate({
    groups: {
        inputGroup: "num1 num2 num3 num4 num5 num6"
    },
    rules: {
        ....
        num1: {
            require_from_group: [6, $("[name^=num]")]
        },
        num2: {
            require_from_group: [6, $("[name^=num]")]
        },
        num3: {
            require_from_group: [6, $("[name^=num]")]
        },
        num4: {
            require_from_group: [6, $("[name^=num]")]
        },
        num5: {
            require_from_group: [6, $("[name^=num]")]
        },
        num6: {
            require_from_group: [6, $("[name^=num]")]
        }
    },
    ...
```

Or a shorter way to assign this rule to all six fields at once...

```
$("[name^=num]").each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add',{
        require_from_group: [6, $("[name^=num]")],
        messages: {
            require_from_group: "These 6 fields are required"
        }
    });
});
```

**DEMO**:  [jsfiddle.net/xbwzt7p9/](http://jsfiddle.net/xbwzt7p9/)

Comment: Thank you! this is what i am looking for!